# How to deal with permissions denied with sbt when on Travis CI?

Tags: sbt, travis-ci

We have had our project running on travis for months and the `.travis.yml` unchanged. However recently we get the rather strange:

> /home/travis/build.sh: line 57: /usr/local/bin/sbt: Permission denied

(note that `sbt` is given by travis and not installed by us).

Changing the permission of `sbt` is also denied (quite obviously but you never know)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The question was answered here: https://github.ibm.com/Whitewater/TravisCI/issues/28

Use `sudo` is the key.